# No Access Region (0x0 through 0xFFFF) within User Virtual Address Space

Tags: windows, pointers, internals, virtual-address-space

I was reading a book on Windows Internals and on a Chapter for Virtual Memory it mentioned that the first 64KB Address range is reserved as a No-Access region and the reason mentioned was to avoid incorrect pointer reference. Can someone explain to me as to why and how this would avoid incorrect pointer reference

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't trap *all* invalid pointer dereferences, just the very common ones.  The kind you get by dereferencing a *null pointer*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I fear it specifically does not address the question (How and Why part)

Comment: This answer was meant to induce an "Ah, of course!" response.  If you don't know what a pointer is then I don't know what you don't know.